# Immutable alternative to CGPoint?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, immutability, cgpoint

As the question states, I would prefer an immutable version of `CGPoint`, `CGSize`, and `CGRect`, although I would rather use a type which is supported by the iOS framework, to avoid converting between types.

So, is there any supported immutable version of `CGPoint`? If not, any recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to protect against?

Comment: No, there isn't such a beast; these aren't objects, they're just C-style structures. Say more about why you want them and what protection you need.

Comment: I plan to handle many 2D points at a time, and many of them might actually represent the same point. This brings up two topics: (a) I would sleep easier if I know nobody can modify them after their creation, and (b) I would like to control the amount of instances I create, preferring to use the same instance multiple times, if possible.

Comment: (c) I actually want to use these points to draw polygons on screen, which is why I'll have to use ``CGPoint`` at some point.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use constant `CGPoint`s etc.

E.g.:

```
const CGSize size = (CGSize){6.0f, 4.0f};
```

Using CGSizeMake won't work as they are not compile time constants and you can't use variables, but this is the closest you'll get to an immutable `CGSize`. If that is not good enough then you'll need to use an object and convert when needed.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how this would work for a larger amount of dynamically created points though. It would not be possible to create an array of ``const CGSize``'s, for example, right?

Answer (score 1):

When a CGPoint (or any other struct - CGRect, etc.) is a property of an Objective-C object, the mechanics of getter/setter methods and the value semantics of C structs means that there is some level of protection against indirectly modifying the value of a CGPoint property of an object. For example, an expression like `someObject.someCGPointProperty.x = 123` will not actually modify the `x` value of the CGPoint owned by `someObject`, because the `someCGPointProperty` accessor will return the CGPoint by value, which means that you are setting the x value on a copy of the CGPoint. To actually modify the CGPoint owned by that object, you would need to do something like:

```
CGPoint point = someObject.someCGPointProperty;
point.x = 123;
someObject.someCGPointProperty = point;
```

Regarding control over the number of instances you create: since CGPoint is a struct, it's passed around by value - effectively it's copied - in function arguments or Objective-C messages. So there's going to be plenty of copies of thees structs moving around anyway. However, these structs are created on the stack, not the heap, and a CGPoint is only 16 bytes (possibly smaller on 32-bit iOS devices?), so it's doubtful you need to worry about any performance implications.

Also, see @hypercrypt's more succinct answer regarding `const` values, as that may address your intentions well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [NSValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) wrapper class. It can wrap a point, a size, a rect and more. It's immutable, so whatever you store inside it can't be changed (remember that if you store a pointer, the memory area to which points can still be changed).

**Example**

```
NSValue* value= [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(x,y)];
```

If you try to set `value.CGPointValue.x` or y you get a compile error. The getter returns just a copy of the `CGPoint` held in the object, so there's no way to change it's value.